# Git, Capistrano, and HTML5 Boilerplate's build script

Tags: git, deployment, capistrano, html5boilerplate

I'm redesigning my personal site and decided to use HTML5 Boilerplate as a starting point, Git for version control, and Capistrano to help deploy. I have Git and Capistrano working correctly and can deploy with `cap deploy`. To get that working, I had to edit the `deploy.rb` file to run `git push origin master` before `deploy:update_code`.

Before using Git and Capistrano, I used to build the website, run HTML5BP's build script, and upload the "Publish" folder it produces.

How can I can still take advantage of HTML5BP's build script while still using Git and Capistrano?

My best guess is to have the build script run on the server at the end of deployment, but I'm not sure how I would do that.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel, I used HTML5BP extensively in Rails applications and never had to run scripts after deployment except at the beginning for minor reconfiguration. I think you need to identify what you need to package/deploy and in some cases Rails 3 can take care of that (asset pipelining, etc)

Comment: Hi Zepplock, I'm using PHP (forgot to mention that!) and the HTML5BP build script exists to minify CSS, JS, optimize images, etc... http://html5boilerplate.com/docs/Build-script/

Comment: If you install `ant` on your production server then you can run all `ant` commands as part of your capistrano scripts. You can add custom commands either before or after deployment.